# Determine highest value of two numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with five columns and two rows.

| Name | Surname | Sum of grades | Number of grades | Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Smith | 30 | 2 | 15 |
| Jack | Decker | 15 | 2 | 7.5 |

I want a message box saying "The best student is (Name & Surname)" based on average.

I tried several things such as declaring maximum of the E range and then getting row number etc.
I've checked the Find and Indirect function.

```vb
Sub BestStudent()

    Dim Maximum As Integer
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim rownumber As Integer
    rownumber = ActiveCell.Row
    Set Rng = Range("E1:E2")
    Maximum = WorksheetFunction.Max(Rng)

    If ActiveCell.Value = Maximum Then
        MsgBox ("The best student is..)

End Sub
```

Comment: That's what I've written so far

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to [ask]. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Voted to reopen based on your latest edit.

Comment: ReOpen Vote to christmas time - seems to be homework.

Comment: A shortcut would be to sort the table and use the first name.

Comment: No because I wanna get this the proper advanced way, because I'm planning to use the name and surname of the best student in order to write him an automated email (which I already know how to do)

Answer (score 2):

Using a sort to get the highest value:

```
    Dim lr As Long
    With Sheet1 'Change to whatever your sheet's code name is
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A2:E" & lr).Sort Range("E2"), xlDescending
        MsgBox "The best student is " & .Cells(2, 1).Value & " " & .Cells(2, 2).Value
    End With
```

Using Max and Find:

```
    Dim maximum As Double
    Dim findrng As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lr As Long
    
    With Sheet1
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("E2:E" & lr)
        maximum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)
        Set findrng = rng.Find(maximum, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not findrng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "The best student is " & .Cells(findrng.Row, 1).Value & " " & .Cells(findrng.Row, 2).Value
        Else
            MsgBox "Something went wrong, Value not found."
        End If
    End With
```

Using a loop:

```
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim maximum As Double
    Dim rownum As Long
    
    With Sheet1
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lr
            If maximum < .Cells(i, 5).Value Then
                maximum = .Cells(i, 5).Value
                rownum = i
            End If
        Next i
    
        MsgBox "The best student is " & .Cells(rownum, 1).Value & " " & .Cells(rownum, 2).Value
    End With
```

Comment: I'll try all of them, will let you know! Many thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

You can do this :

```
    Dim Maximum As Double    
    Dim i, lastline As Integer    
    Dim names As String
    
    names = ""    
    Range("E2").Select
    
    ' get maximum
    Maximum = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)))
    'get last line
    lastline = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    For i = 2 To (lastline + 1)
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(i, 5).Value = Maximum Then
            If names = "" Then
 
                names = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(i, 2).Value
            Else
                names = names & " and " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(i, 2).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox "The best student is (are) : " & names
```